# Rhino-ETL Conditional Operation

Tags: rhino-etl

I want to check the value of a row field value and depending on the value run a specific operation. Can this be done. Part of the code is below

```
public override IEnumerable<Row> Execute(IEnumerable<Row> rows)
    {
        foreach (Row row in rows)
        {
            if (row["ProductAction"] == "Update")
            {
                _updateProductOperation.Execute(rows);
            }
            else
            {
                _addProductOperation.Execute(rows);
            }

            yield return row;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Someone answered me on another forum in case any one is interested. They said you'd do this with a branching operation were the one branch would check for "Update" and the other would check for != "Update".